# Using project painting, texture obtained is much darker then the images projected

Tags: uv, light, texture-painting

I'm using images to project-paint my model with the stencil brush.
After I painted, the texture originated, and ofcourse the uv layout image, is much darker then the photos originally used.

I tried changing the shading settings, adding lamps aimed directly to the model, but it seems to only effect the model itself and not the texture. On top of that I tried saving the image and externally edit it, increasing brightness or contrast, but it wrecks the fine details.

Anyone, any ideas? thank you!

[image: as you can see, the texture and the uv layout is way darker then the image projected, on the right]

Comment: Did you have the strenght of your strokes set to 1?

Comment: I guess the one your are talking about is the menu in the texture brush->tools->stroke. I'm adding a printscreen of it to the question because it doesn't have the option of "strength". Please don't spare details about the stroke feature because it's the first time I've heard of it. What settings in the stroke menu do I need to change? @joshsanfelici

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Is the strenght in the tool tab  set to 1?